# javascript carousel not workong

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

i'm trying to make a carousel with different slides in my website with javascript through a youtube tutorial i followed  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HcxHDS2w1s&t=605s, but it's not working, i checked my code and there is no mistake in it

here is my html and js:

```
<script>
        
        //carousel script
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-carousel-button]")

        buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const offset = button.dataset.carouselButton === "next" ? 1: -1
        const slides = button.closest("[data-carousel]").querySelector('[data-slides]')

        const activeSlide = slides.querySelector("[data-active]")
        let newIndex = [...slides.children].indexOf(activeSlide) + offset
        if(newIndex < 0) newIndex = slides.children.length - 1
        if(newIndex >= slides.children.length) newIndex = 0

        slides.children[newIndex].dataset.active = true
        delete activeSlide.dataset.active
     })
})
        </script>
        <div class="carousel" data-carousel>

            <button class="carousel-button prev" data-carousel-button="prev">Vorige</button>
            <button class="carousel-button next" data-carousel-button="next">Volgende</button>

            <ul data-slides>
                <li>
                    <div class="Slide" data-active>
                        <div class="Avatar"></div>
                        <div class="InfoHeader"><h1>Wie ben ik?</h1></div>
                        <div class="Info1">Mijn naam is Mohammed, ik ben 18 jaar oud en mijn passie is om te creëren. zelf ben ik een hard werkende man die achterzijn doelen aan gaat. Ik snap hoe belangrijk het is om te hard werken, om iets van je leven te maken!</div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="Slide">
                        <div class="Avatar"></div>
                        <div class="InfoHeader"><h1>Mijn Studie.</h1></div>
                        <div class="Info1">Ik Studeer Software Development op Vista College in Heerlen op MBO niveau 4, deze studie heb ik gekozen omdat geïnteresseerd ben in engineering en Software engineer als mijn vervolg opleiding wil doen op het HBO.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="Slide">
                        <div class="Avatar"></div>
                        <div class="InfoHeader"><h1>Wie ben ik?</h1></div>
                        <div class="Info1">Mijn naam is Mohammed, ik ben 18 jaar oud en mijn passie is om te creëren.</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </section>
```

and here is my css:

```
.carousel{
position: relative;

}

 .Slide{
 position: absolute;
 inset: 0;
 opacity: 0;
}

.Slide[data-active]{
 opacity: 1;
}

.carousel > ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

 .carousel-button.prev{
 background-color: #1378d6;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 320%;
 left: 55%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 padding: 5px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 border: none;
 z-index: 10;
 }

.carousel-button.next{
 background-color: #1378d6;
 border-radius: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 320%;
 left: 62%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 padding: 5px;
 border: none;
 z-index: 10;
 }

.carousel-button:focus{
  background-color: #6db9ff;
}

.Avatar{
 vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("../img/Avatar10.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  left: 15%;
   top: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 9px  black;

 }


.InfoHeader{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 40%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 277%;
  font-family: arial black;
  text-shadow: 9px 9px 3px black;
 }


 .Info1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 130%;
  left: 40%;
  color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 138%;
  text-shadow: 9px 9px 3px black;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

can someone please explain why it isn't working? thankyou

Comment: There is a complete code from the lesson: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/js-css-carousel

Answer (score 0):

You need to move **data-active** attribute to the li to work this correctly. Also need to adjust the css.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-carousel-button]")

        buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const offset = button.dataset.carouselButton === "next" ? 1: -1
        const slides = button.closest("[data-carousel]").querySelector('[data-slides]')

        const activeSlide = slides.querySelector("[data-active]")
        let newIndex = [...slides.children].indexOf(activeSlide) + offset
        if(newIndex < 0) newIndex = slides.children.length - 1
        if(newIndex >= slides.children.length) newIndex = 0

        slides.children[newIndex].dataset.active = true
        delete activeSlide.dataset.active
     })
})
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;

}

.Slide {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

li[data-active] .Slide {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel>ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel-button.prev {
  background-color: #1378d6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 320%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-button.next {
  background-color: #1378d6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 320%;
  left: 62%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-button:focus {
  background-color: #6db9ff;
}

.Avatar {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("../img/Avatar10.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  left: 15%;
  top: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 9px black;

}

.InfoHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 40%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 277%;
  font-family: arial black;
  text-shadow: 9px 9px 3px black;
}

.Info1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130%;
  left: 40%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 138%;
  text-shadow: 9px 9px 3px black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel" data-carousel>

  <button class="carousel-button prev" data-carousel-button="prev">Vorige</button>
  <button class="carousel-button next" data-carousel-button="next">Volgende</button>

  <ul data-slides>
    <li data-active>
      <div class="Slide">
        <div class="Avatar"></div>
        <div class="InfoHeader">
          <h1>Wie ben ik?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="Info1">Mijn naam is Mohammed, ik ben 18 jaar oud en mijn passie is om te creëren. zelf ben ik een hard werkende man die achterzijn doelen aan gaat. Ik snap hoe belangrijk het is om te hard werken, om iets van je leven te maken!</div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="Slide">
        <div class="Avatar"></div>
        <div class="InfoHeader">
          <h1>Mijn Studie.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="Info1">Ik Studeer Software Development op Vista College in Heerlen op MBO niveau 4, deze studie heb ik gekozen omdat geïnteresseerd ben in engineering en Software engineer als mijn vervolg opleiding wil doen op het HBO.</div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="Slide">
        <div class="Avatar"></div>
        <div class="InfoHeader">
          <h1>Wie ben ik?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="Info1">Mijn naam is Mohammed, ik ben 18 jaar oud en mijn passie is om te creëren.</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```